# How to import existing ec2 instance in aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

Does anyone know how to import an existing ec2 instance in aws account using aws CDK?

I searched on the net , also went through the docs.
no luck there!

All helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should import existing VPC or subnet , right ?

Comment: you can definitely import vpc and subnets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#importing-an-existing-vpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a custom static method which has the implementation, this would be similar to the implementation of RDS : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/DatabaseInstanceBase.html

from_database_instance_attributes does a similar job and this can be replicated.