# Get IP address from EC2 Instance id using the aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

How can a get the private IP address of an existing EC2 instance when I just have the instance id using the AWS CDK in Typescript?

Comment: Probably this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001725/13126651

Comment: I think is not the same case. I just want to get the IP address, not import it to the CDK.

Comment: You can interact with resource which are not created by cdk without importing because cdk at this point does not know there is resource already present